# Compiling modified version of Okular with new highlighting tool

Tags: compiling, libraries, docker, okular

Regarding the post [Modify Okular highlight to automatically copy highlighted text into comment](https://superuser.com/questions/673917/modify-okular-highlight-to-automatically-copy-highlighted-text-into-comment/1115352#1115352), I need help for the process to follow in order to compile [Okular hicksor version](https://superuser.com/a/1115352/989973) on Ubuntu 18.04. I have actually tried hard many times with different methods but never succeeded...

I'm a bit lost with notions from the [related post](https://superuser.com/a/1115352/989973):

> pre-built binary

and

> To make the build process reproducible, I added a Dockerfile